# How to get a static amazonaws.com subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2

I have an instance on EC2 that needs to be accessed by some external customers. Unfortunately, their IT network has a whitelist. This whitelist allows amazonaws.com domains, but does not allow the static Elastic IP that this public DNS domain maps to nor does it allow the external domain that I mapped to this static IP.

So what I really need is something like http://[MyCompanyAndApp].amazonaws.com domain.
Is there a way to get this?

Edit:
To answer some of your questions below.
The "domain name" I'm referring to is the "generic ip style hostname like 123-234-23-89.server.amazon.com".

Yes, it seems they have a whitelist (it's a very secure facility apparently). I've given them this generic ip style hostname and they have no problem accessing it. But giving them the Elastic IP that it maps to doesn't work. Giving them my company's domain that maps to the Elastic IP doesn't work either. (It works for me though)

Comment: Why on earth would their IT whitelist all of AmazonAWS.com but not be willing to whitelist your domain or IP?

Comment: What is providing amazonaws.com? In all my usage of AWS they've never provided a "domain name" for a server (other than a generic ip style hostname like 123-234-23-89.server.amazon.com).

Also can you explain how they will whitelist a domain name but not an IP? Or they won't whitelist "myapp.mycompany.com" ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to obtain a static AmazonAWS.com subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

If their IT organization is checking reverse DNS, then you can apply for Amazon to add a custom reverse DNS entry for an Elastic IP address you assign to an instance:

> https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

It's done in the guise of applying for email whitelist, but you get the reverse DNS as a side-benefit.

Their IT folks would then need to add your hostname to their exception list.

If their IT folks don't trust you enough to let their users access your server, then you're going to have a tough time.

Comment: I believe I have already done this.

This is what I have.
1) I have a public DNS for my instance something like ec2-173.76...amazonaws.com.
2) I have a static Elastic IP (e.g. 173.76...) which I've associated with that instance
3) I created a subdomain that points to that static IP (e.g. http://aws.mycompany.com --> 173.76...)

I've asked our customers to try all 3 urls. All 3 work for me but only (1) works for them.

Comment: You have set up forward DNS, but probably not reverse DNS.  It isn't clear if reverse DNS is required.  In fact, it isn't at all clear what is required by the IT organization.  You'd probably be best working more closely with them if they want to give their users access to your server.